# Specific HTML parsing with Python 3 and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, httpie

I am trying to parse the info in the bottom right table of the following link, the table that says `Current schedule submissions`:

> dnedesign.us.to/tables/

I was able to parse it down to:

```
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"14:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"16:30";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"14:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"15:30";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"16:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"18:30";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:0:"";s:7:"endTime";s:0:"";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:0:"";s:7:"endTime";s:0:"";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"12:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"16:30";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"12:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"16:30";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:6:"Sunday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"12:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"14:30";}
{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:3:"Day";s:7:"Tuesday";s:9:"startTime";s:5:"14:30";s:7:"endTime";s:5:"16:30";}
```

and here is the code that performs the parsing to get the above:

```
try:
    from urllib.request  import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://dnedesign.us.to/tables/'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
for rows in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for td in rows.find_all('td'):      
        if 'a:' in td.text:
            print(td.text[4:])
```

I am trying to parse it down to the following:

```
Day:Tuesday    Starttime:14:30    Endtime:16:30
Day:Sunday     Starttime:12:30    Endtime:14:30
Day:Sunday     Starttime:12:30    Endtime:16:30
Day:Sunday     Starttime:12:30    Endtime:16:30
....
....
```

And so on for the rest of the table.

I am using `Python 3.6.9` and `Httpie 0.9.8` on `Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1`. This is for my graduation project, any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Neil M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to parse the well-formed table data, taking care to look out for empty strings:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://dnedesign.us.to/tables/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
data = []

for rows in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for td in rows.find_all('td'):      
        if 'a:' in td.text:
            cols = re.findall(r"s:\d+:\"(.*?)\"", td.text)
            data.append({cols[x]: cols[x+1] for x in range(0, len(cols), 2)})

for row in data[::-1]:
    row = {
        k: re.sub(
            r"[a-zA-Z]+", lambda x: x.group().capitalize(), "%s:%s" % (k, v)
        ) for k, v in row.items()
    }
    print("    ".join([row["Day"], row["startTime"], row["endTime"]]))
```

Output:

```
Day:Tuesday    Starttime:14:30    Endtime:16:30
Day:Sunday    Starttime:12:30    Endtime:14:30
Day:Sunday    Starttime:12:30    Endtime:16:30
Day:Sunday    Starttime:12:30    Endtime:16:30
Day:Sunday    Starttime:    Endtime:
Day:Sunday    Starttime:    Endtime:
Day:Sunday    Starttime:16:30    Endtime:18:30
Day:Sunday    Starttime:14:30    Endtime:15:30
Day:Sunday    Starttime:14:30    Endtime:16:30
```

The second stage creates strings to your format specification, but the intermediate step of creating the `data` list to store key-value pairs of column data for each row is the meat of the work.

---

In terms of your request to put the items into a class, you can create an instance of `Schedule` and populate relevant fields instead of using a dictionary:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Schedule: 
    def __init__(self, day, start, end): 
        self.day = day
        self.start = start 
        self.end = end 


url = 'http://dnedesign.us.to/tables/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
schedules = []

for rows in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for td in rows.find_all('td'):      
        if 'a:' in td.text:
            cols = re.findall(r"s:\d+:\"(.*?)\"", td.text)
            data = {cols[x]: cols[x+1] for x in range(0, len(cols), 2)}
            schedules.append(Schedule(data["Day"], data["startTime"], data["endTime"]))

for schedule in schedules:
    print(schedule.day, schedule.start, schedule.end)
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. For some reason I get the input inverted as such, first column is end time , second is start time and the last column is day:

Endtime:16:30    Starttime:14:30    Day:Tuesday
Endtime:14:30    Starttime:12:30    Day:Sunday
Endtime:16:30    Starttime:12:30    Day:Sunday
Endtime:16:30    Starttime:12:30    Day:Sunday
Endtime:    Starttime:    Day:Sunday
Endtime:    Starttime:    Day:Sunday
Endtime:18:30    Starttime:16:30    Day:Sunday
Endtime:15:30    Starttime:14:30    Day:Sunday
Endtime:16:30    Starttime:14:30    Day:Sunday

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Updated! Although dicts are sorted in Python 3.6, I'm working in 3.4 and didn't take into account the original key ordering. Let me know if this doesn't work out for you.

Comment: Works now, thank you. I would like to modify the program slightly by creating a class and storing the parsed elements in the class so they can be saved and used later, it is a requirement for the project I am working on. Something like the following 
'class Schedule:
  def __init__(day, start, end):
    day.start = start
    day.end = end

Saturday = Schedule(22:00:00, 23:00:00)

print(Saturday.start)
print(Saturday.end) '

@@ggloren would this be possible?

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but I recommend accepting the answer to this question if the problem is solved and opening a new question with the fresh set of requirements and your attempt so far.

Comment: Thank you. I will make a new post. As for the answer, I did accept it. But because I have accepted below 15 answers because my account is new it is not showing but they say that they recorded my response. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @ggloren Sorry for the late reply , but for some reason I can't run this program.

Comment: The letter u is printed next to all parsed elements